# Intuition behind the definition of extrinsic curvature of a submanifold

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, curvature, submanifold

The extrinsic curvature $\mathcal{K}_{ij}$ of a sub-manifold (say, a boundary $\partial M$ of a manifold $M$) is defined as

$$\mathcal{K}_{ij} \equiv \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}_{n}h_{ij} = \nabla_{(i)}n_{j)},$$

where $n$ is the inward-pointing unit normal to $\partial M$ and $h_{ij}$ is the induced metric on $\partial M$.

Is there an intuitive way to understand why the above must be the definition of the extrinsic curvature of a submanifold?

Comment: There's no "must" about it; choosing the outward unit normal field gives a different sign. Presumably the inward-pointing normal is merely more convenient for your author's purposes. (Separately, by "submanifold" in the question title, you mean "the boundary of a region", which is a much more special condition.) As for the presumed intent of your question, have you thought of what the extrinsic curvature is for a plane or cylinder or sphere in Euclidean three-space, and what information is captured? (Or is that not what you're asking?)

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking. Could you give an intuitive picture of the above formulae for extrinsic curvature using a plane or cylinder or sphere in Euclidean three-space?